# Elasticsearch partial update collection

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch API in my Spring boot project and I have the following DeviceVO class:

```
@Document(indexName = "devices", type = "device")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DeviceVO {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.text)
    private String name;

    //other fields

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Set<DeviceTagVO> deviceTags;

    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
}
```

I need to partially update this document by adding/removing tags to the DeviceTag set.

I know I can user following for updating an attribute:

```
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
        indexRequest.source("name", newName);
        UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(DeviceVO.getId()).withClass(DeviceVO.class).withIndexRequest(indexRequest).build();
        elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
```

How can I add remove items to a set using an update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jest(used by Spring) doesn't support this yet, we used an inline script inside the update query:

```
private void updateSearchIndexRemoveDeviceTag(DeviceVO deviceVO, DeviceTagVO tag) {


        String scriptTagId = "{\n" +
                "  \"script\": {\n" +
                "    \"lang\": \"painless\",\n" +
                "    \"inline\": \"(ctx._source.deviceTagIds = ctx._source.deviceTagIds ?: []).remove(ctx._source.deviceTagIds.indexOf(params.tags))\",\n" + //check if device tags is null
                "    \"params\": {\n" +
                "      \"tags\": \"" + tag.getId() + "\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        try {
            client.execute(new Update.Builder(scriptTagId).index("devices").type("device").id(deviceVO.getId()).build());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ElasticSearchException("error.updating.device.index", "remove device tag from index");
        }
    }
```